# mylocationoverlay disappears first time it find location

Tags: android, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

I am trying to setup a mylocationoverlay. Unfortunately, it is acting quite strangely. It works fine, except it does not appear until after I leave the MapActivity  and come back in my application. Initially the map appears and there is a blue circle while it is getting a fine location. However, instead of resolving to a point, the circle just disappears.

My Code looks like this:

```
onResume() {
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(getActivity(), mp);
myLocation.enableMyLocation();
myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable(){
       public void run() {
          map.getOverlays().clear();
      map.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
      map.postInvalidate();
       }
    }
}


onPause() {
  myLocation.disableMyLocation();
  layout.removeView(map);
  map = null;
```

}

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening here? Since this is pretty much verbatim what all the examples online look like, I might add that I am testing this on a motorolla atrix running 2.3.4.

Comment: after added your overlay you have to populate() on map view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Edit :` Let me take you through your code:

```
onResume() {
// First time: draw a circle somewhere here. There is no GPS fix yet, so no dot. 
// Second time: The dot from the previous fix exists, so you get a circle and dot.
myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(getActivity(), mp);
myLocation.enableMyLocation();
myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable(){
       public void run() {
       // First time: removes the circle and draws a dot.
       // Second time: removes the circle and dot, and draw a new dot. 
       map.getOverlays().clear();
       map.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
       map.postInvalidate();
       }
    }
}
```

---

`map.getOverlays().clear();` removes the circle

use `remove()` instead to remove the overlay(s) that you don't want, instead of clearing them all.

Remember to call  `map.invalidate();` whenever you need to force a redraw

Comment: I used remove instead and it still doesn't show up the first time. I also put in a log statment to show how many overlays there were on the map and it said 1, even though nothing was shown. I think this mat mean that the draw method isn't getting called?

Comment: I should also add that when the blue circle appears the first time, it does not include the dot at the center. Then the blue circle disappears leaving me with no overlay. The second time I open the activity, the blue circle is there initially, but includes an overlay dot at the center. Then once the circle disappears the dot is still left there. I am completely at a loss for why it doesn't work the first time!